# Invesion symmetry is not point group symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, graphene

I am currently reviewing a paper available at this link:
https://www.nature.com/articles/srep17571

In the introduction, the explanation caught my attention:  "Due to the stability of the Dirac cone with respect to small deformations, the protection of the Dirac cone is not attributed to point group symmetry. Instead, inversion symmetry and time reversal symmetry are under consideration."

This has led me to wonder whether inversion symmetry is distinct from point group symmetry. Could you provide some clarification?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm just trying to guess: inversion symmetry is something like $\vec{x} \to -\vec{x}$, where $\vec{x}$ is any point in space, while a point group symmetry also includes rotations by a discrete set of angles

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.